# How to export User cert with private key in PKCS12 format

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, certificate, client-certificate

I'm running Win2008R2, and have installed an Enterprise CA. I can create user certs, but no matter what I do, I cannot export the private key. I'm using the un-touched User certificate template, and the "allow export of private key" option is selected. Still, whenever I go to the "export" dialogue of the certificate (both as user and as administrator), I don't get asked if I want to export the private key, and the option to select PKCS12 format is grayed out.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you *have* the associated private key.

Double-click on the certificate entry, make sure it shows *"You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate"* at the bottom.

[image: Certificate properties]

Comment: good point! i actually don't. just wonder why -- i requested cert through MMC cert snap-in. after approving the request in the ca, the cert is in certificates/activedirectoryuserobject. but no private key. how do i get a cert with private key?

Comment: accepting this as it actually answers my question. doesn't really help, though, as long as I cannot create a certificate with a corresponding private key ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but I believe, that the export of private keys only works for keys that have been imported into the system and not for those which have been created inside of it.

Comment: Not necessarily. As long as the private key is marked as "exportable", it can be exported.